# How to write this MongoDB (Aggregate) query into C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to perform group-by with the `$max` operator in MongoDB. I figure out the query which is working in the MongoDB database but was not able to write the same using C#.

```
db.getCollection('Employee').aggregate(
[  
    {$unwind : "$Projects"},
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$EmpId",
            "LastUpdated" : {"$max" : "$Projects.LastUpdated"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Below C# code is giving an error:

> "Projects" is not valid property.

```cs
_db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection).Aggregate().Unwind(i=>i.Projects)
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide sample data and model class being used? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Assume this is your sample data:

```json
[{
  "EmpId": 1,
  "Projects": [
    {
      "LastUpdated": {
        "$date": "2021-10-22T16:00:00Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "LastUpdated": {
        "$date": "2021-11-07T16:00:00Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "LastUpdated": {
        "$date": "2022-01-22T16:00:00Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

and this is your model class:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeProject> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeProject
{
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

---

To use the `Projects` property, you need to specify your collection as `Project` type as:

```cs
_db.GetCollection<Employee>("Employee")
```

**Solution 1: Mix use of AggregateFluent and BsonDocument**

```cs
var result = _db.GetCollection<Employee>("Employee")
                .Aggregate()
                .Unwind(i => i.Projects)
                .Group(new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "_id", "$EmpId" },
                    { "LastUpdated", new BsonDocument("$max", "$Projects.LastUpdated") }
                })
                .ToList();
```

---

**Solution 2: Full use of AggregateFluent**

**Pre-requisites:**

- Need to create a model for unwinded `Project`.

```cs
public class UnwindEmployeeProject
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public EmployeeProject Projects { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var result = _db.GetCollection<Employee>("Employee")
               .Aggregate()
               .Unwind<Employee, UnwindEmployeeProject>(i => i.Projects)
               .Group(
                   k => k.EmpId,
                   g => new
                   {
                       EmpId = g.Key,
                       LastUpdated = g.Max(x => x.Projects.LastUpdated)
                   })
               .ToList();
```

---

**Solution 3: Full use of BsonDocument**

With Mongo Compass, you can [export your query to C#](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/export-query-to-language/).

```cs
PipelineDefinition<Employee, BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$Projects"),
    new BsonDocument("$group",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", "$EmpId" },
            { "LastUpdated",
                new BsonDocument("$max", "$Projects.LastUpdated") }
        })
};

var result = _db.GetCollection<Employee>("Employee")
                .Aggregate(pipeline)
                .ToList();
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Upvoted your answer. Useful reference for the `BsonDocument` class in the C# MongoDb Driver, [click here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/bson/#create-a-bson-document)