MongoDB LINQ crashes using Aggregate on Android
I have a MongoDB database on Atlas that keeps details of books I have read.  There are two collections: an authors one and a books one.
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Author
{
    [BsonId][BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("first")] public string? first { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("last")] public string? last { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("author_id")] public BsonInt32? author_id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("FullName")][BsonIgnoreIfNull] public string? FullName { get; set; }

}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Book
{
    [BsonId][BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("title")] public string? title { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("title_id")] public BsonInt32? title_id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("author")] public string? author { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("issue_date")] public string? issue_date { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("return_date")] public string? return_date { get; set; }
}

There are 485 authors and 1452 books. The database provides data for an Android app created using MAUI.  One of the pages provides a list of which authors have the most books in the database.  This uses a LINQ group query.
public async Task<List<Popular>> GetPopular()
{
    IMongoQueryable<Popular>? query = (from book in booksCollection.AsQueryable()
                                       group book by book.author into g
                                       let lastBook = g.OrderByDescending(b => b.return_date).FirstOrDefault()
                                       select new Popular
                                       {
                                           Author = g.Key,
                                           Count = g.Count(),
                                           ReturnDate = lastBook.return_date,
                                           Title = lastBook.title
                                       }).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count).ThenBy(g => g.Author).Take(10);
    List<Popular>? popular = await query.ToListAsync();
    return popular;
}

A lot of the time this runs correctly and produces the list.  However it does crash on the query.ToListAsync statement at random.
**MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Ast.Optimizers.AstGroupingPipelineOptimizer+UnableToRemoveReferenceToElementsException:**
 'Exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Ast.Optimizers.AstGroupingPipelineOptimizer+UnableToRemoveReferenceToElementsException' was thrown.'

I'm using Visual Studio 17.11.4 with MongoDB.Driver 2.9 that has LINQ 3 as the default.  Is there an easy way to convert the query to use Builders or BsonDocument, or is there an error in the LINQ I've used?

If you are looking for an aggregation query: https://mongoplayground.net/p/KeTWGNf1FiJ. And to work with MongoDB .NET Driver: you may look for Solution 3 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839664/how-to-write-this-mongodb-aggregate-query-into-c-sharp/70842890#70842890

I sorted this out with the aid of Studio3T (3T Software Labs Ltd https://studio3t.com).  This is an excellent product for building queries for MongoDB with Free and Pro versions.  I've replaced the linq with a BsonDocument query that doesn't crash!
